# socket.io leave current room and join after button is clicked

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, chatroom

my question is about socket rooms and leave and joining in rooms .my problem is that : i am creating chatroom and i want whenever user (socket) clicks "next person"  button (in my case link)  i want socket to disconnect (leave) its current room and join another one where another socket is waiting for second socket.    like in *Omegle*

## Heading

so i tried this code

client-side:

```
 N.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                 socket.emit('next')

});

socket.on('next',function(){
socket.disconnect()
document.GetElementById('divd').style.display = "inline";
socket.connect()
});
```

server-side:

```
       socket.on('next', function(){
        socket.leave(socket.current_room)
        chnm.in(socket.current_room).emit('next');
        socket.join(room)
        });
```

but whenever i click "next" it only shows both socket disconnect div like in disconnect event but does not lets socket which triggered that event to join other room 
 rooms in my case is like that

```
   var room = "room" + numb;
   socket.current_room = room;
```

but what i want is to show in room (where socket disconnected) that socket disconnected and socket which triggered that event to be joined in other room . 
(example: in room 1 socket triggered "next" link   he/she disconnects from the room 1 and joins to room 2  and in room 1 appears disconnect div, i think it will appear anyway if i use socket.disconnect() because i already created disconnect event . thanks guys for help <3

Comment: The usual way you would leave one room and join another is to send your server a message asking it to do a `socket.leave(oldRoom)` and `socket.join(newRoom)` on your behalf.  There is no need to drop the connection and reconnect just to change rooms.

Comment: can u show me an example i get a bit confused , because i think i am doing what u are saying

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's still not enough code shown or enough of the overall design described that you're trying to achieve, but here's what I can see from what you've shown so far.

Here's your sequence of events:

1. User clicks button
2. Client code does `socket.emit('next')`
3. Server receives `next` message
4. Server calls `socket.leave(socket.current_room)` to leave the current room
5. Server does a `.emit('next')` to everyone still in that room
6. Server calls `socket.join(room)` (I have no idea where the `room` variable comes from)
7. Clients receive `next` message and that causes them to `socket.disconnect() and then`socket.connect()` (no idea why it's doing that).

The things that seem odd to me about this sequence of events are:

1. The `socket.disconnect()` followed by the `socket.connect()` is completely unnecessary and probably causing problems.  First off, these events are asynchronous.  If you really wanted to do one followed by the other, you need to wait for the disconnect to finish before trying to do the reconnect.  But, mostly, there should be no reason to disconnect and then reconnect.  Just update the state of the connection you already have.
2. I don't follow why when you assign someone to a new room, you then disconnect everyone else who was in that room.
3. Please don't use the same message name `next` to mean one thing when the client receives it and something completely different when the server receives it.   This isn't a programming error per se, but it really makes your code hard to understand.  Give each its own descriptive name.